# Automatically change /etc/hosts on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, permissions, hosts-file

I edit `/etc/hosts` as a first line of defense to stop me going to certain distracting sites during the working day.

Ideally I'd like to have two versions of `hosts` and a cron job that switches them at 9am and 5pm during the day, but I think that there is a permissions issue running `cron` under `sudo`... should I just reduce the permissions on `hosts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to change permissions of any system file.

I don't see any issue just doing everything under `root`, i.e. by opening a root shell, and editing the crontab.

```
sudo -i
crontab -e
```

You can also directly edit `root`'s crontab with:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```